# On the asymptotic $\pi(x+h(x)) - \pi(x) \sim \frac{h(x)}{\log x} \ (x \to \infty)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $h(x)$ be a function that is positive on $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and satisfies $h(x) = o(x)$ and $(\log x)^a = o(h(x))$ for all $a > 0$, as $x \to \infty$.  Is it reasonable to expect  under these conditions that
$$\pi(x+h(x)) - \pi(x) \sim \frac{h(x)}{\log x}  \ (x \to \infty)?$$
In other words, do any known conjectures suggest this to be true under these conditions on $h$, or conversely, do any known results or conjectures imply that this is false for some such $h$?

This relates to a question I recently asked on the Stack Exchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4759659/examples-of-functions-h-for-which-asymptotic-pixhx-pix-sim-frach/4759669#4759669

Comment: See Granville's ICM 1994 talk "Unexpected Irregularities in the Distribution of Prime Numbers". In the bottom of p. 393 he writes "It is plausible that (5) holds uniformly if $\log y/ \log \log x \to \infty$" where (5) is "$\pi(x+y)-\pi(x) \sim \frac{y}{\log x}$".

Comment: I assume this translates, more precisely, to the statement: for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists an $N>1$ such that
$$1-\varepsilon \leq \frac{\pi(x+y)-\pi(x)}{y/\log x} \leq 1+\varepsilon$$
for all $x \geq N$ and all $y > 0$ with $N\log \log x \leq \log y \leq \log x$.  Is that fair?

Comment: The standard way to interpret the kind of statement that Ofir quoted is that if you fix a slowly growing function $y(x)$ satisfying $\log y/\log\log x \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$, then $\pi(x+y(x)) - \pi(x) \sim \frac{y(x)}{\log x}$. I think that's strictly stronger than what you said.

Comment: @Anurag Sahay.  I think my statement is stronger than your interpretation.  I was trying to make sense of Granville's use of the word "uniformly".  Does it have any significance or can you remove it from his statement and the meaning stays the same?

Comment: @JesseElliott Indeed, your statement is equivalent to Granville's (and to Anurag's). Letting $R(x,y) =(\pi(x+y)-\pi(x))/(y/\log x) - 1$, I would interpret the word 'uniformly' as referring to using the quantity $N(x,A) =\sup_{x \ge y \ge (\log x)^A} |R(x,y)|$ (involving a supremum, as in the definition of uniform convergence, say) and saying $N(x,A) \to 0$ as $\min\{A,x\} \to \infty$ (which is equivalent to your statement).

Comment: @AnuragSahay To see Jesse Elliott's formulation follows from yours, assume in contradiction that Jesse Elliott's statement is false, meaning there is an $\varepsilon>0$ such that for every $N>1$ there exist $(x_N,y_N)$ with $x_N \ge N$ and $N \log \log x_N \le \log y_N \le \log x_N$ while $|R(x_N,y_N)| \ge \varepsilon$. 
But this refutes your statement by taking $y(x)$ such that $y(x_N)=y_N$. (Certainly $y(x)/\log \log x \to \infty$ along a subsequence; to construct such a $y$ with $y(x)/\log \log x \to \infty$ you can assume w.l.o.g that $x_N$ increases and use a step-function.)

Comment: @OfirGorodetsky  Thank you for the clarification!